# How to export jasper report to excel formatting fields

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a jasper report with output to excel, but the `"java.math.BigDecimal"` values ​​are displayed as text.

I already tried to use the property such but converted only the `"java.lang.Double"` and `"java.lang.Integer"` values ​​to numerical, the `"java.math.BigDecimal"` fields continue to be displayed as text.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

Does anyone know of any way to convert this type of field `"java.math.BigDecimal"` to a numerical type cell in excel? is it possible to do this conversion?

Comment: Add after export xls or xlsx and then try.

Comment: I tried, but the BigDecimal types continue to text. I'm almost giving up.

Comment: Have you used number pattern to your column ? If not, try applying number format and then use property. <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>

Comment: No, I don't use any pattern, I will try it now!

Comment: show the jrxml of the textField that is not displayed correct in excel, maybe you are formatting it as a String in the textField expression.

Comment: @PetterFriberg, i use $F{Fieldname}, without any format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem
with a line in java. I don't know why, but i change **DetectCellType** to true in java and now works.

My code:

```
        JRXlsExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
        SimpleXlsReportConfiguration xlsReportConfiguration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
xlsReportConfiguration.setDetectCellType(true);
            xlsExporter.setConfiguration(xlsReportConfiguration);
```